# How to handle error while executing Flux.map()

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I´m trying to figure out how handle errors when mapping elements inside a Flux.

For instance, I´m parsing a CSV string into one of my business POJOs:

```
myflux.map(stock -> converter.convertHistoricalCSVToStockQuotation(stock));
```

Some of this lines might contain errors, so what I get in the log is:

```
 reactor.core.publisher.FluxLog:  onNext([SOME_BOGUS_QUOTE]@38.09 (Fri Apr 08 00:00:00 CEST 2016) H(38.419998)/L(37.849998)/O(37.970001))
 reactor.core.publisher.FluxLog:  onNext([SOME_BOGUS_QUOTE]@38.130001 (Thu Apr 07 00:00:00 CEST 2016) H(38.189999)/L(37.610001)/O(37.799999))
 reactor.core.publisher.FluxLog:  onError(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid CSV stock quotation: SOME_BOGUS_QUOTE,trololo)
 reactor.core.publisher.FluxLog:  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid CSV stock quotation: SOME_BOGUS_QUOTE,trololo
```

I read in the API some error handling methods, but most refered to returning an "error value" or using a fallback Flux, like this one:

```
Flux.onErrorResumeWith(myflux, x -> Mono.fromCallable(() -> ... do stuff);
```

However, using this with my `myflux` means that the whole flux is processed again.

So, is there a way to handle errors while processing particular elements (I.e ignoring them/Logging them) and keep processing the rest of the flux?

**UPDATE with @akarnokd workaround**

```
public Flux<StockQuotation> getQuotes(List<String> tickers)
{
    Flux<StockQuotation> processingFlux = Flux.fromIterable(tickers)
    // Get each set of quotes in a separate thread
    .flatMap(s -> Mono.fromCallable(() -> feeder.getCSVQuotes(s)))
    // Convert each list of raw quotes string in a new Flux<String>
    .flatMap(list -> Flux.fromIterable(list))
    // Convert the string to POJOs
    .flatMap(x -> {
            try {
                return Flux.just(converter.convertHistoricalCSVToStockQuotation(x));    
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException ex){
                System.out.println("Error decoding stock quotation: " + x);
                return Flux.empty();
            }
    });

    return processingFlux;
}
```

This works as a charm, however, as you can see the code is less elegant than before. Does not the Flux API have any method to do what this code does?

```
retry(...)
retryWhen(...)
onErrorResumeWith(...)
onErrorReturn(...)
```

Comment: You may be able to use a custom exception which can include the failed element as a variable in it. Then in the onError method, you can get the failed element through the getter method in the custom exception.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need `flatMap` instead which let's you return an empty sequence if the processing failed:

```
myflux.flatMap(v -> {
    try {
        return Flux.just(converter.convertHistoricalCSVToStockQuotation(stock));
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        return Flux.empty();
    }
});
```

Comment: Works great (gonna accept this answer) but I would like to know whether this can be done with the API. If not, I will open a feature request. Thanks!

Comment: This is the de-facto standard API to perform such behavior. Errors are terminal events and you have to transform them into something else in lambdas to avoid termination.

Comment: Ok. I proposed the creation of a new method to handle individual failures (perhaps publishing those failures as a "dead letter" flux?). Maybe this could be helpful...

Answer (score 21):

If you want to use Reactor 3's methods for dealing with exceptions, you can use `Mono.fromCallable`.

```
flatMap(x -> 
    Mono.fromCallable(() -> converter.convertHistoricalCSVToStockQuotation(x))
        .flux()
        .flatMap(Flux::fromIterable)
        .onErrorResume(Flux::empty)
)
```

Unfortunately there is no `Flux.fromCallable`, so assuming the callable returns a list, you have to convert it to a Flux manually.

Answer (score 9):

With the current version of Reactor 3, quite a few methods have been added. So we could do something like so:

```
Flux.onErrorResume(error -> { 
        System.out.println("Error decoding stock quotation: " + e);
        return Flux.empty();
    });
```

See more info on how to handle errors [here](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#error.handling)

Answer (score 4):

You can use onErrorContinue. 
It allows recovering from errors by dropping the trouble element and continuing with the subsequent elements.

Answer (score 2):

```
...
       // Convert the string to POJOs
    .flatMap(x ->
        Flux.just(converter.convertHistoricalCSVToStockQuotation(x))
            .doOnError(IllegalArgumentException.class,
                e -> System.out.println("Error decoding stock quotation: " + x))
            //.onErrorStop()
            .onErrorResume(IllegalArgumentException.class, e -> Flux.empty())
    )
...
```

Comment: Using `just` means that the calculation will not be done "inside" the Mono/Flux, so the error will not be handled by it.